# Show that there are finitely many geodesics between two points

Tags: differential-geometry

I am having a hard time with the proof of the following two problems which are extremely similar:

1. Show that between two points, $p, q \in Z$ of the cylinder,  $Z = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R| x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$, there exists infinitely many geodesics.
2. Prove that between two points $p,k \in K$ of the circular cone, $K = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R : x^2+y^2 = z^2\} $ finitely many geodesics exist.

I'm thinking that the proof starts with assuming towards contradiction that there are finitely many geodesics for the first one, and for the second problem, that there are  infinitely many geodesics.  Any help is appreciated as I am completely lost on where to go from here.

Comment: I do not think it's true that there are only finitely many geodesics between any pair of points on the cylinder - what makes you think there are?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo! Fixed it. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: You've edited point 2, my comment was about point 1

Comment: Sorry, got a little flustered trying to edit it so quickly. Fixed it now!

Comment: To show that there exist infinitely many, it suffices to construct an infinite family of geodesics. Take for example the points $p=(1,0,0)$ and $q=(1,0,2\pi)$ and model cylinder as in infinite strip with width $2\pi$  with it's two edges glued together. The strip, like the cylinder, has zero intrinsic curvature, so they have the same geodesics. Now consider lines which leave $p$ with slope $1/n$ for $n\in\{1,2,...\}$. Show that each such line wraps around the cylinder $n$ times before reaching $q$. This gives the required infinite family for part 1.

Comment: For part 2, again unrolling the cone to a pair of infinite segments, and considering lines may help you.

Comment: I tried to unravel the cone and found that the geodesics unlike the straight lines of the cylinder are curves? Is this correct? From here, I am a bit stuck as now I am unsure how these infinitely many curves imply the finitely many geodesics.  Does it have to do with the angle of the curves on the unrolled cone?

Comment: No, the cone also has zero intrinsic curvature, so geodesics on the cone unroll to straight lines on the infinite segments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136221/discussion-between-richie-and-david-sheard).